# How to trace high CPU Apache process to particular virtualhost

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, cpu-usage

Looking at the output of `top` I notice that intermittently there are one or two Apache processes consuming a high amount of CPU - anywhere between 50% - 90%

The spikes in CPU usage come and go quite quickly every 10 seconds or so.

There are various other Apache processes running which consume somewhere between 2% - 4%

I've researched all the various ways of trying to track down which virtualhost/website is responsible for these processes.  However, because they come and go quickly I can't find a reliable way of doing this.

I've tried `lsof` and also looking at the output of `server-status` but because the processes don't last long the process ID gets re-used and it's not possible to tie it down to the virtualhost that's causing the issue.

For example, if I run `lsof` on the process ID in question, it lists a dozen different virtualhost log files which have shared that process ID in the last few seconds.  I'm convinced there is one virtualhost at fault but I can't figure out which one.

I've also checked the MySQL slow query log and this doesn't reveal anything of interest.

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation: add response time to your logs.

It's not perfect, as there's no guarantee that the spike-causing requests take longer to serve than others, but it is likely, and gives you a starting point for investigation.

To do this, you'll want to define a new LogFormat and CustomLog which includes the %D parameter. See the Apache [mod_log_config documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html).

Another option which is probably a bit too low-level but could give you an idea of the nature of the load, would be to strace the apache parent process with -f to follow children, and -c to show the cpu time per-call, e.g. `strace -f -c -p <apache parent pid>`

Once you know the system calls that are taking the most time, you can then trace them directly. For example, say the server is spending a lot of time doing write(), you could then do `strace -f -e trace=write -p <apache parent pid>`, and look at those calls in more detail.